# How secure is storing a password in a component's property in an Angular 7 app?

Tags: angular

I'm writing an Angular 7 application that needs to display some data retrieved from a server running a command through an SSH connection. To get the data, the user types a username and a password and the app makes a call to the backend, which uses these credentials to open an SSH connection with a server and return the requested information.

The data needs to be refreshed every 30 seconds so, to avoid asking the user for his credentials over and over, I store them in the properties of an object inside the appropriate component in the application. This has made me wonder how secure they are. There are tools (f.i. Augury for Chrome) that lets you inspect (in dev mode) all the properties of the components in the application and its values. Is it possible to get those values from an application in production mode?

Thanks!

Comment: storing user name and password ?????

Comment: Hi, I don't store any password anywhere in the application, but for this particular case I thought it would be the only way, as the API call needs the credentials every time...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing their password why not use sessions/localStorage, say `UserLoggedIn = 1|0`, to just check if the user is logged in or not based on that variable. If they login you change it from `0 to 1` or `true to false`.

To answer your question, I don't see the problem in having/saving the password in the application scope as long as it's properly encrypted but I still don't think it's not the best of ideas.

Comment: I use localStorage for the main logging system, but I didn't think it could be useful in this case because each API call is independent of each other so I need to send the password everytime. This is the main reason for storing it and, although I would keep it encrypted, I'm quite concerned about security so we'll rewrite the backend methods to use sessions instead.

Comment: Oh, I clearly understand you now. So '...as long as it's properly encrypted' should still be a valid statement. Also Tweaking the backend to use some sort of encoded/encrypted session key instead of the password itself is still a good idea